# Extension of linear independent set of vectors, with a span, that doesn't contain the standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I need the following statement as part of a longer proof. It has been some time since I learned linear algebra and I can't figure out why this holds.

Let $d,N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $d < N$. Let $\mathcal{A} := \{a_1,...,a_d\}$ be a linear independent set of $d$ vectors from $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ ($a_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}$, $a_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}$,...), furthermore none of the vectors in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ should be contained in $span(\mathcal{A})$ ($(1,0,...,0)^T \notin span(\mathcal{A})$ **and** $(0,1,0,...,0)^T \notin span(\mathcal{A})$, ...) . I'm looking for vectors $b_1,...,b_{N+1-d}$ such that $\tilde{\mathcal{A}} := \{a_1,...,a_d,b_1,...,b_{N+1-d}\}$ is still an linear independent set **and** none of the vectors in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ is in $span(\tilde{\mathcal{A}})$.

My idea was to proof this through the basis extension theorem, but I'm struggleing finding a vectorspace $V$, such that $span(\mathcal{A}) \subset V$ and none of the vectors in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ is in $V$. In other words I'm struggleing to find a vectorspace, that does **not** contain $(1,0,...,0)^T, (0,1,0,...,0)^T, ...$, but does contain every linear combination of vectors from $\mathcal{A}$.

Sorry for my spotty english and sorry if I oversee an easy solution. Every help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have such an $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$, then it would span all of $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ and thus contain every standard basis vector.

It is impossible to construct a **linearly independent** set of $N+1$ vectors that don’t contain the standard basis vectors (or any other vector, for that matter).

Comment: You can get close, though. Consider the vectors $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}; \quad \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$ These vectors span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that misses every standard basis vector. I’m not sure if you can always *extend* the vectors in $\mathcal{A}$ to a set of $N$ vectors with this property, though.