# Extend a subspace to a codimension-1 subspace not containing the standard basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

This was inspired by [a recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3179791/274352).

---

Let $A = \{a_1, \dots, a_k\}$ be a linearly independent set of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and assume that the standard basis vectors are not in the span of $A$.

> Can I always find vectors $b_{k+1},\dots, b_{n-1}$ such that $X = \{a_1,\dots, a_k, b_{k+1},\dots, b_{n-1}\}$ spans an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace also not containing the standard basis vectors?

---

Certainly, such a subspace exists in general: take the subspace spanned by vectors $v_i$ the first and the $i^{th}$ components are $1$ and the rest are $0$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^4$ this is

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}; \quad \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}; \quad \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Thus, my question is answered in the case where $A = \emptyset$. **Is it always possible in general?** If not, are there any conditions on the vectors in $A$ that allows such an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer I was told in person that I quite like which uses induction.

Certainly, if $|A| = 0$ this is possible.

Now, assume that $|A| = k < n-1$. Let $A_i$ be the span of $A$ together with the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector. By the hypothesis, we know that $A_i$ is a $k+1$ dimensional subspace. **Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be expressed as a finite union of proper subspaces**, the set

$$\mathbb{R}^n - \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)$$

is nonempty. Let $v$ be some vector in the above set, and consider the subspace spanned by $A$ and $v$. This subspace is $k+1$ dimensional and does not contain any standard basis vectors.

---

Note that this proof generalizes to a proof of the following, more general statement:

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $A$ a linearly independent  collection of $k<n$ vectors in $F^n$.
>
> For any finite set of vectors $S$ not contained in the span of $A$, there is an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace containing $A$ that does not contain any vectors in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should always be possible. If $|{A}| = n-1$ then there is nothing to prove.

Say $|{A}| = k < n-1$. Let $V$ be the span of $A$, so that $V$ is a $k$-dimensional hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$. Consider the collection of $k+1$ dimensional hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^n$ that contain $V$. Since $k+1 < n$ there are infinitely many such hyperplanes. At most $n$ of them could contain a standard basis vector. Hence there is a $k+1$ dimensional hyperplane, $V'$, that contains $V$ and contains no standard basis vector. Extend $A$ to a basis of $V'$ and repeat.